# How to update one row that has max value in column (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the Rows that have the Max score with the value of 'Yes' in the Text1 column.

This is straightforward except when there are multiple rows with the max score.

If they have the same score, I just want to select the top row to have the value 'Yes'. Only one row with identical Vendor IDs should have the 'Yes' value.

```sql
    UPDATE Suppliers
        SET Text1='Yes'
        --SELECT DISTINCT *
        FROM Suppliers INNER JOIN
            (
            SELECT Vendor, MAX(VCScore) as MaxVCScore
            FROM Suppliers 
            GROUP BY Vendor
            ) maxTable
        ON Suppliers.Vendor=maxTable.Vendor
        AND Suppliers.VCScore=maxTable.MaxVCScore
```

I do not want to use TOP 1 because that will only update one row in the whole table. I instead want only one row for each Vendor to be updated. (Vendor can be identical which is what I am trying to fix.) I cannot add a Group By clause to the Update statement as I would like to group by Vendor but that is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t as (
select * , row_number() over (partition by Vendor order by VCScore desc) rn
from Suppliers
)

update s
set Text1 = 'Yes'
from supplier s
join t on s.pkey = t.pkey and t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried Row_Number previously, but I was trying to use Group By with it instead of Partition By in the Over clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you may about this using a Common Table Expression (CTE). The following may be run in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @Suppliers table ( Vendor varchar(20), VCScore int, Text1 varchar(3), SupplierPK int IDENTITY (1,1) );
INSERT INTO @Suppliers ( Vendor, VCScore ) VALUES
    ( 'Vendor1', 85 ), ( 'Vendor1', 85 ), ( 'Vendor1', 85 ), ( 'Vendor2', 65 ), ( 'Vendor2', 65 );

DECLARE @Vendor table ( Vendor varchar(20), VCScore int );
INSERT INTO @Vendor VALUES
    ( 'Vendor1', 85 ), ( 'Vendor1', 25 ), ( 'Vendor1', 45 ), ( 'Vendor2', 45 ), ( 'Vendor2', 65 );

WITH cte AS (

    SELECT
        Vendor,
        Text1,
        SupplierPK,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Vendor ORDER BY SupplierPK ) AS RowNo
    FROM @Suppliers AS s
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT MAX ( VCScore ) AS MaxVCScore FROM @Vendor AS v WHERE v.Vendor = s.Vendor 
    ) AS x
    WHERE
        s.VCScore = x.MaxVCScore

)
UPDATE cte
SET
    Text1 = 'Yes'
WHERE
    cte.RowNo = 1;

SELECT * FROM @Suppliers ORDER BY Vendor, SupplierPK;
```

Returns

```
+---------+---------+-------+------------+
| Vendor  | VCScore | Text1 | SupplierPK |
+---------+---------+-------+------------+
| Vendor1 |      85 | Yes   |          1 |
| Vendor1 |      85 | NULL  |          2 |
| Vendor1 |      85 | NULL  |          3 |
| Vendor2 |      65 | Yes   |          4 |
| Vendor2 |      65 | NULL  |          5 |
+---------+---------+-------+------------+
```

I am making the assumption that you have a primary key value that can be sorted in your Suppliers table.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.* ,
             row_number() over (partition by Vendor order by VCScore desc) as seqnum
      from Suppliers s
     )
update toupdate
    set Text1 = 'Yes'
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that no `JOIN` is needed.